# Display transparent gif file in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, gif

How can I display a gif image on a windows form while making it transparent at a value, say, 70%?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Transparency with WinForms is a big issue.. You might as well just change the image to reflect what is drawn behind it.

Comment: Wrong: Transparency with WinForms is NOT a big issue at all. If you have for example a transprent PNG image it is done with 3 lines of code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is called alpha channel. Unfortunately, it is not supported for GIFs. From [this article](http://www.icongalore.com/xp-icon-articles/alpha-channel-explained.htm):

> TIFF, TGA, PNG, PSD and GIF all support alpha but really only PNG and
>   GIF are used for applications, and the web. Gif, however, uses a
>   special type of alpha. Instead of the alpha channel in a GIF image
>   containing degrees of transparency it only has an on/off transparency.
>   This means that pixels within a **GIF image can either be fully opaque
>   or fully transparent**. There is no in between.

It is possible to paint an image with custom opacity programmatically. See these:

- [Using Graphics.DrawImage() to Draw Image with Transparency/Alpha Channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658994/using-graphics-drawimage-to-draw-image-with-transparency-alpha-channel)
- [.DrawImage with opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519956/drawimage-with-opacity)
- [How to implement Alpha blending](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5034/How-to-implement-Alpha-blending)
- [Alpha Blending using GDI+](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9778/Alpha-Blending-using-GDI)

Comment: what's the difference between `gif` and `GIF`?

Comment: @Chin: letter casing. Functionally the same.

Answer (score 0):

You just can choose 0% or 100% transparent for a GIF, but not any value between them.