# c# transparent spinning wheel (or gif) is just half transparent

Tags: c#

Well, first try was with a readily made spinning wheel (a gif). After that, I found a code that dynamically generates a wheel, but no way in both cases to have full transparency.

Depending on what I set as parent (form or panel) and the position on my wheel on form, the spin is just half transparent.

[image]

I use C# express (VS 2008).

All I want is a nice wheel in center of form, activated when BG is doing something, but full transparent so I can resize form.

Thanks,

Update: 
I worked on some code that is draw a spinning wheel just fine. Almost working except OnPantBackground() which needs to be empty to paint behind, but in this case, a black rectangle is drawn because of ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer enabled.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace WinFormsControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A label that can be transparent.
    /// </summary>
    public class TransparentLabel : Control
    {
        // Constants =========================================================
        private const double NumberOfDegreesInCircle = 360;
        private const double NumberOfDegreesInHalfCircle = NumberOfDegreesInCircle / 2;
        private const int DefaultInnerCircleRadius = 8;
        private const int DefaultOuterCircleRadius = 10;
        private const int DefaultNumberOfSpoke = 10;
        private const int DefaultSpokeThickness = 4;
        private readonly Color DefaultColor = Color.DarkGray;

        private const int MacOSXInnerCircleRadius = 5;
        private const int MacOSXOuterCircleRadius = 11;
        private const int MacOSXNumberOfSpoke = 12;
        private const int MacOSXSpokeThickness = 2;

        private const int FireFoxInnerCircleRadius = 6;
        private const int FireFoxOuterCircleRadius = 7;
        private const int FireFoxNumberOfSpoke = 9;
        private const int FireFoxSpokeThickness = 4;

        private const int IE7InnerCircleRadius = 8;
        private const int IE7OuterCircleRadius = 9;
        private const int IE7NumberOfSpoke = 24;
        private const int IE7SpokeThickness = 4;

        // Enumeration =======================================================
        public enum StylePresets
        {
            MacOSX,
            Firefox,
            IE7,
            Custom
        }

        // Attributes ========================================================
        private Timer m_Timer;
        private bool m_IsTimerActive;
        private int m_NumberOfSpoke;
        private int m_SpokeThickness;
        private int m_ProgressValue;
        private int m_OuterCircleRadius;
        private int m_InnerCircleRadius;
        private PointF m_CenterPoint;
        private Color m_Color;
        private Color[] m_Colors;
        private double[] m_Angles;
        private StylePresets m_StylePreset;

        // Properties ========================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the lightest color of the circle.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The lightest color of the circle.</value>
        [TypeConverter("System.Drawing.ColorConverter"),
         Category("LoadingCircle"),
         Description("Sets the color of spoke.")]
        public Color Color
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Color;
            }
            set
            {
                m_Color = value;

                GenerateColorsPallet();
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the outer circle radius.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The outer circle radius.</value>
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("Gets or sets the radius of outer circle."),
         System.ComponentModel.Category("LoadingCircle")]
        public int OuterCircleRadius
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_OuterCircleRadius == 0)
                    m_OuterCircleRadius = DefaultOuterCircleRadius;

                return m_OuterCircleRadius;
            }
            set
            {
                m_OuterCircleRadius = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the inner circle radius.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The inner circle radius.</value>
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("Gets or sets the radius of inner circle."),
         System.ComponentModel.Category("LoadingCircle")]
        public int InnerCircleRadius
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_InnerCircleRadius == 0)
                    m_InnerCircleRadius = DefaultInnerCircleRadius;

                return m_InnerCircleRadius;
            }
            set
            {
                m_InnerCircleRadius = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the number of spoke.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The number of spoke.</value>
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("Gets or sets the number of spoke."),
        System.ComponentModel.Category("LoadingCircle")]
        public int NumberSpoke
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_NumberOfSpoke == 0)
                    m_NumberOfSpoke = DefaultNumberOfSpoke;

                return m_NumberOfSpoke;
            }
            set
            {
                if (m_NumberOfSpoke != value && m_NumberOfSpoke > 0)
                {
                    m_NumberOfSpoke = value;
                    GenerateColorsPallet();
                    GetSpokesAngles();

                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this <see cref="T:LoadingCircle"/> is active.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value><c>true</c> if active; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("Gets or sets the number of spoke."),
        System.ComponentModel.Category("LoadingCircle")]
        public bool Active
        {
            get
            {
                return m_IsTimerActive;
            }
            set
            {
                m_IsTimerActive = value;
                ActiveTimer();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the spoke thickness.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The spoke thickness.</value>
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("Gets or sets the thickness of a spoke."),
        System.ComponentModel.Category("LoadingCircle")]
        public int SpokeThickness
        {
            get
            {
                if (m_SpokeThickness <= 0)
                    m_SpokeThickness = DefaultSpokeThickness;

                return m_SpokeThickness;
            }
            set
            {
                m_SpokeThickness = value;
                Invalidate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the rotation speed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The rotation speed.</value>
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("Gets or sets the rotation speed. Higher the slower."),
        System.ComponentModel.Category("LoadingCircle")]
        public int RotationSpeed
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Timer.Interval;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    m_Timer.Interval = value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Quickly sets the style to one of these presets, or a custom style if desired
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The style preset.</value>
        [Category("LoadingCircle"),
         Description("Quickly sets the style to one of these presets, or a custom style if desired"),
         DefaultValue(typeof(StylePresets), "Custom")]
        public StylePresets StylePreset
        {
            get { return m_StylePreset; }
            set
            {
                m_StylePreset = value;

                switch (m_StylePreset)
                {
                    case StylePresets.MacOSX:
                        SetCircleAppearance(MacOSXNumberOfSpoke,
                            MacOSXSpokeThickness, MacOSXInnerCircleRadius,
                            MacOSXOuterCircleRadius);
                        break;
                    case StylePresets.Firefox:
                        SetCircleAppearance(FireFoxNumberOfSpoke,
                            FireFoxSpokeThickness, FireFoxInnerCircleRadius,
                            FireFoxOuterCircleRadius);
                        break;
                    case StylePresets.IE7:
                        SetCircleAppearance(IE7NumberOfSpoke,
                            IE7SpokeThickness, IE7InnerCircleRadius,
                            IE7OuterCircleRadius);
                        break;
                    case StylePresets.Custom:
                        SetCircleAppearance(DefaultNumberOfSpoke,
                            DefaultSpokeThickness,
                            DefaultInnerCircleRadius,
                            DefaultOuterCircleRadius);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Creates a new <see cref="TransparentLabel"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        public TransparentLabel()
        {
            TabStop = false;

            InitializeComponent();

            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            //SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);

            m_Color = DefaultColor;

            GenerateColorsPallet();
            GetSpokesAngles();
            GetControlCenterPoint();

            m_Timer = new Timer();
            m_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(aTimer_Tick);
            ActiveTimer();

            this.Resize += new EventHandler(LoadingCircle_Resize);

            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint |
                          ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
                          ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
                          ControlStyles.ContainerControl |
                          ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
                          ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor
                          , true);


        }

        // Events ============================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Resize event of the LoadingCircle control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        void LoadingCircle_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetControlCenterPoint();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the Tick event of the aTimer control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
        /// <param name="e">The <see cref="T:System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
        void aTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_ProgressValue = ++m_ProgressValue % m_NumberOfSpoke;
            Invalidate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the creation parameters.
        /// </summary>
        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
                return cp;
            }
        }



        // Overridden Methods ================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the size of a rectangular area into which a control can be fitted.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="proposedSize">The custom-sized area for a control.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// An ordered pair of type <see cref="T:System.Drawing.Size"></see> representing the width and height of a rectangle.
        /// </returns>
        public override Size GetPreferredSize(Size proposedSize)
        {
            proposedSize.Width =
                (m_OuterCircleRadius + m_SpokeThickness) * 2;

            return proposedSize;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Paints the background.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">E.</param>
        /// 

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // do nothing
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Paints the control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">E.</param>
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //DrawText();


            if (m_NumberOfSpoke > 0)
            {
                e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

                int intPosition = m_ProgressValue;
                for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < m_NumberOfSpoke; intCounter++)
                {
                    intPosition = intPosition % m_NumberOfSpoke;
                    DrawLine(e.Graphics,
                             GetCoordinate(m_CenterPoint, m_InnerCircleRadius, m_Angles[intPosition]),
                             GetCoordinate(m_CenterPoint, m_OuterCircleRadius, m_Angles[intPosition]),
                             m_Colors[intCounter], m_SpokeThickness);
                    intPosition++;
                }
            }


            base.OnPaint(e);


        }

        /*
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            if (m.Msg == 0x000F)
            {
                DrawText();
            }
        }

        private void DrawText()
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics())
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(ForeColor))
            {
                SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(Text, Font);

                // first figure out the top
                float top = 0;
                switch (textAlign)
                {
                    case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
                    case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                    case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                        top = (Height - size.Height) / 2;
                        break;
                    case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
                    case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                    case ContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                        top = Height - size.Height;
                        break;
                }

                float left = -1;
                switch (textAlign)
                {
                    case ContentAlignment.TopLeft:
                    case ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft:
                    case ContentAlignment.BottomLeft:
                        if (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
                            left = Width - size.Width;
                        else
                            left = -1;
                        break;
                    case ContentAlignment.TopCenter:
                    case ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter:
                    case ContentAlignment.BottomCenter:
                        left = (Width - size.Width) / 2;
                        break;
                    case ContentAlignment.TopRight:
                    case ContentAlignment.MiddleRight:
                    case ContentAlignment.BottomRight:
                        if (RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes)
                            left = -1;
                        else
                            left = Width - size.Width;
                        break;
                }
                graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, left, top);
            }
        }
         */
        /*
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the text associated with this control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// The text associated with this control.
        /// </returns>
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Text = value;
                RecreateHandle();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether control's elements are aligned to support locales using right-to-left fonts.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value></value>
        /// <returns>
        /// One of the <see cref="T:System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft"/> values. The default is <see cref="F:System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Inherit"/>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="T:System.ComponentModel.InvalidEnumArgumentException">
        /// The assigned value is not one of the <see cref="T:System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft"/> values.
        /// </exception>
        public override RightToLeft RightToLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return base.RightToLeft;
            }
            set
            {
                base.RightToLeft = value;
                RecreateHandle();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the font of the text displayed by the control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value></value>
        /// <returns>
        /// The <see cref="T:System.Drawing.Font"/> to apply to the text displayed by the control. The default is the value of the <see cref="P:System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefaultFont"/> property.
        /// </returns>
        public override Font Font
        {
            get
            {
                return base.Font;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Font = value;
                RecreateHandle();
            }
        }

        private ContentAlignment textAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the text alignment.
        /// </summary>
        public ContentAlignment TextAlign
        {
            get { return textAlign; }
            set
            {
                textAlign = value;
                RecreateHandle();
            }
        }
        */
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }


        // Methods ===========================================================
        /// <summary>
        /// Darkens a specified color.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_objColor">Color to darken.</param>
        /// <param name="_intPercent">The percent of darken.</param>
        /// <returns>The new color generated.</returns>
        private Color Darken(Color _objColor, int _intPercent)
        {
            int intRed = _objColor.R;
            int intGreen = _objColor.G;
            int intBlue = _objColor.B;
            return Color.FromArgb(_intPercent, Math.Min(intRed, byte.MaxValue), Math.Min(intGreen, byte.MaxValue), Math.Min(intBlue, byte.MaxValue));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates the colors pallet.
        /// </summary>
        private void GenerateColorsPallet()
        {
            m_Colors = GenerateColorsPallet(m_Color, Active, m_NumberOfSpoke);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates the colors pallet.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_objColor">Color of the lightest spoke.</param>
        /// <param name="_blnShadeColor">if set to <c>true</c> the color will be shaded on X spoke.</param>
        /// <returns>An array of color used to draw the circle.</returns>
        private Color[] GenerateColorsPallet(Color _objColor, bool _blnShadeColor, int _intNbSpoke)
        {
            Color[] objColors = new Color[NumberSpoke];

            // Value is used to simulate a gradient feel... For each spoke, the 
            // color will be darken by value in intIncrement.
            byte bytIncrement = (byte)(byte.MaxValue / NumberSpoke);

            //Reset variable in case of multiple passes
            byte PERCENTAGE_OF_DARKEN = 0;

            for (int intCursor = 0; intCursor < NumberSpoke; intCursor++)
            {
                if (_blnShadeColor)
                {
                    if (intCursor == 0 || intCursor < NumberSpoke - _intNbSpoke)
                        objColors[intCursor] = _objColor;
                    else
                    {
                        // Increment alpha channel color
                        PERCENTAGE_OF_DARKEN += bytIncrement;

                        // Ensure that we don't exceed the maximum alpha
                        // channel value (255)
                        if (PERCENTAGE_OF_DARKEN > byte.MaxValue)
                            PERCENTAGE_OF_DARKEN = byte.MaxValue;

                        // Determine the spoke forecolor
                        objColors[intCursor] = Darken(_objColor, PERCENTAGE_OF_DARKEN);
                    }
                }
                else
                    objColors[intCursor] = _objColor;
            }

            return objColors;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the control center point.
        /// </summary>
        private void GetControlCenterPoint()
        {
            m_CenterPoint = GetControlCenterPoint(this);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the control center point.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>PointF object</returns>
        private PointF GetControlCenterPoint(Control _objControl)
        {
            return new PointF(_objControl.Width / 2, _objControl.Height / 2 - 1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the line with GDI+.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_objGraphics">The Graphics object.</param>
        /// <param name="_objPointOne">The point one.</param>
        /// <param name="_objPointTwo">The point two.</param>
        /// <param name="_objColor">Color of the spoke.</param>
        /// <param name="_intLineThickness">The thickness of spoke.</param>
        private void DrawLine(Graphics _objGraphics, PointF _objPointOne, PointF _objPointTwo,
                              Color _objColor, int _intLineThickness)
        {
            using (Pen objPen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(_objColor), _intLineThickness))
            {
                objPen.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
                objPen.EndCap = LineCap.Round;
                _objGraphics.DrawLine(objPen, _objPointOne, _objPointTwo);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the coordinate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_objCircleCenter">The Circle center.</param>
        /// <param name="_intRadius">The radius.</param>
        /// <param name="_dblAngle">The angle.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private PointF GetCoordinate(PointF _objCircleCenter, int _intRadius, double _dblAngle)
        {
            double dblAngle = Math.PI * _dblAngle / NumberOfDegreesInHalfCircle;

            return new PointF(_objCircleCenter.X + _intRadius * (float)Math.Cos(dblAngle),
                              _objCircleCenter.Y + _intRadius * (float)Math.Sin(dblAngle));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the spokes angles.
        /// </summary>
        private void GetSpokesAngles()
        {
            m_Angles = GetSpokesAngles(NumberSpoke);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the spoke angles.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_shtNumberSpoke">The number spoke.</param>
        /// <returns>An array of angle.</returns>
        private double[] GetSpokesAngles(int _intNumberSpoke)
        {
            double[] Angles = new double[_intNumberSpoke];
            double dblAngle = (double)NumberOfDegreesInCircle / _intNumberSpoke;

            for (int shtCounter = 0; shtCounter < _intNumberSpoke; shtCounter++)
                Angles[shtCounter] = (shtCounter == 0 ? dblAngle : Angles[shtCounter - 1] + dblAngle);

            return Angles;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Actives the timer.
        /// </summary>
        private void ActiveTimer()
        {
            if (m_IsTimerActive)
            {
                m_Timer.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                m_Timer.Stop();
                m_ProgressValue = 0;
            }

            GenerateColorsPallet();
            Invalidate();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the circle appearance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="numberSpoke">The number spoke.</param>
        /// <param name="spokeThickness">The spoke thickness.</param>
        /// <param name="innerCircleRadius">The inner circle radius.</param>
        /// <param name="outerCircleRadius">The outer circle radius.</param>
        public void SetCircleAppearance(int numberSpoke, int spokeThickness,
            int innerCircleRadius, int outerCircleRadius)
        {
            NumberSpoke = numberSpoke;
            SpokeThickness = spokeThickness;
            InnerCircleRadius = innerCircleRadius;
            OuterCircleRadius = outerCircleRadius;

            Invalidate();
        } 




    }
}
```

Comment: Looks transparent to me, the form's background is visible.  You can make extra sure by setting the form's BackgroundImage property.  Making it transparent against the form *and* the panel, well, that takes a [more work](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943454/winforms-how-to-create-a-control-transparent-to-other-controls).  Consider moving it up a bit.  Or WPF.

Comment: Hans, thank you for link. This is exactly my problem, transparent for both! It's frustrating :) Do you have a more precise example so I can adapt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display transparent gif file in windows form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655743/display-transparent-gif-file-in-windows-form)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own post, but after testing a lot of projects, modify without success, I finally found one that is almost full transparent

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27185/WYSIWYG-Progress-Circle-for-NET-Framework-C

That guy made a very well job almost 10 years ago, at least inner part of spin is copied and re-drawn in OnPaint so quite nice transparent over RichTextBox control where all other projects failed :)

The only small problem is that the circle trail, don't copy the bmp behind so there will always be a comet effect, but I can live with that! Much pleasant effect than other solutions, including few on stackoverflow.

In case anyone will need!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Wow that seems incredibly complicated. I don't know much about wpf, but on iOS what we usually do is load an image that has the exact properties we need (here, transparent background), and just rotate the image to make the spinning effect.

You only need very little logic to make it appear/disappear and rotate. For a very basic spinner you get to create and use that class in a matter of seconds.

At least that's the route I'd go for, instead of writing 300 lines of code to manually handle the spinner :p

Comment: indeed, drives me nuts already :( I need a simple preloader with BG transparent across all form controls. I don't use WPF, it's plain winforms and I am not expert on this. Hoping that a good programmer will help me.