# Convert BMP image to PNG with C#. Alpha channel changing?

Tags: c#, image

I have Bitmap image with alpha channel transparency. I am converting this BMP image to PNG format. Here is my code:

```
string tmp = @"c:\mypath\imageName";
using (Bitmap changeFormat = new Bitmap(tmp+".bmp"))
{
    changeFormat.Save(tmp + ".png", ImageFormat.Png)
}
```

Everything is okay. I now have a PNG image but alpha channel is now white instead of transparent (which it was in the BMP image).

Ps:test window XP, that PNG imgae when open in window 7 it ok . And open with Gimp soft.

Comment: Take a look at this questions and it's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658994/using-graphics-drawimage-to-draw-image-with-transparency-alpha-channel

Comment: Thank but not my problem. I need change Image Type with all channel don't change.

Comment: I check bmp by PixelFormat property and result is "Format32bppRgb". ??
My bmp image is 32bit RBGA image. in bitmap header binary show: 42 47 52 73

Comment: Can you add the image or one that reproduces the issue to your question?