# Losing alpha channel information opening a BMP file

Tags: c#, winforms, bmp, fromfile

I have a BMP file which I know is 32bpp and contains alpha information.  Whenever I use the System.Drawing.Bitmap class's constructor, or FromFile, it loads it as 32bppRgb instead of 32bppArgb.  Is there a way to keep the alpha information?
I know BMP is a simple file format for which I could write my own loader, but I would rather not.  It seems like there should be an option somewhere.

Comment: This is somewhat related.  Perhaps it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658994/using-graphics-drawimage-to-draw-image-with-transparency-alpha-channel

Comment: Loading bmps with alpha channels doesn't appear to be supported. See this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2f81979d-30f0-4a41-9c5e-ff49c28ab814/loading-image-from-32-bits-bitmap-file?forum=csharpgeneral.

Comment: You can not load.bmp formats supporting alpha.

Comment: It supports alpha for PNG files - are you constrained to using only BMP, or do you have the potential to switch formats?

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I had read the GIF transparency article before posting.  The other article was quite enlightening.
I am not constrained to BMP, I was trying to support both PNG and BMP.  I have put BMP support on hold until I can load them manually.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, GDI+ does not support alpha channels in BMP files. Here's the relevant note in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The Image class does not support alpha transparency in bitmaps. To
>   enable alpha transparency, use PNG images with 32 bits per pixel.

Your best bet is to either convert the file to a format that supports transparency (like PNG) in a separate program that supports BMP alpha, or write your own code to do it.